# have a table with 1000+ columns, how to load data into snowflake table with parquet files without explicitly specify the column name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

for the snowflake document, it has 3 columns with loading from a parquet file then you can use:
"copy into cities
from (select
$1:continent::varchar,
$1:country:name::varchar,
$1:country:city::variant
from @sf_tut_stage/cities. parquet);
"

If have 1000+ columns, can I not list all the columns like $1:col1, $1:col2...$1:co1000?

Comment: copy into cities from @sf_tut_stage/cities.parquet // to load all

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check out our INFER_SCHEMA function to dynamically obtain the columns/datatypes. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html
The expression column should be able to get you 95% of the way there.

```
select *
  from table(
    infer_schema(
      location=>'@mystage'
      , file_format=>'my_parquet_format'
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

First number of columns(if possible name of the columns) should match with the staged parquet file.

Create a target table from your parquet file:

````
select *
  from table(
    infer_schema(
      location=>'@mystage'
      , file_format=>'my_parquet_format'
      )
    );```

Now load the data into parquet table
```copy into target from @stage/filename.parquet
  on_error = 'continue',
  FILE_FORMAT = 'parquet_format',
  MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = 'CASE_INSENSITIVE';```
````